# Python: Force Virtual Environments to use system certificate store on Windows

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

My company uses a VPN, which does not work with the PIP certificate check out of the box. When I install a package with `pip install asyncio`, it gives me the following error:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/asyncio/

In the system wide python installation, this can be circumvented by using:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip-system-certs
```

After that, the Windows certificate store is used, which contains the CA for the VPN. Now, I can just use:

```
pip install asyncio
```

and all works fine.

However, if I use a virtual environment, I am back in the same position of having to first install pip-system-certs:

```
python -m venv C:\location\of\venv
cd C:\location\of\venv
.\Scripts\activate
pip install asyncio
```

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/asyncio/

This makes working with systems like Poetry very difficult, because all configurations need to change.

Is there a way to force all Python Virtual Environments on my system to use the system certificate store?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but on a Linux machine. What solved the problem for me was the following:

1. check where the certificate is stored in your "global" environment
2. check the same for the virtual environment. Use, for example

   ```
   >> python3 -m certifi
   output is something like this:
   /path/to/global_env/certificate1.crt
   ```
3. replace the virtual environment's certificate with that of the global environment

   ```
   mv /path/to/global_env/certificate1.crt /path/to/virtualenv/certificate2.pem
   ```

Now the same certificate file is used in both environments.

Comment: Thank you for the response! However, for me it was fixed by a complete reïnstall of my system, and now, for some reason, the certificates work. No clue how or why...

Since I can not try your solution, I can not accept it as solved either. But I do appreciate you take the time to answer!